# Datepicker not showing proper field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails version 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

I'm trying to make within a form_tag a datepicker field.
In my GemFile I have added gem 'jquery-rails', gem 'jquery-ui-rails' and gem 'jquery_datepicker'.
In the rails console I have used the command: rails generate jquery:install --ui

Application.js looks like this:

```
 // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
    // listed below.
    //
    // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
    // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
    //
    // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
    // the compiled file.
    //
    // WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
    // GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
    //
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery_ui.all
    //= require_tree .

$(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"});
});
```

Application.css:

```
    /*
     * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
     * listed below.
     *
     * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
     * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
     *
     * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
     * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
     *
     *= require_self
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_jquery.ui.all
    */

And in the view:

<%= form_tag url: {action: 'do_something'} do |f| %>
        <%= text_field_tag :birth_date, '', :class => "datepicker" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Do something man!"%>
        <% end %>
```

What's the proper calling of datepicker function for form_tag?

Update1: In chromium browser, debugging $(".datepicker") returns null..
Edited my Files(Thanks Sagar.Patil)

FinalUpdate: I still haven't found a solution regarding this issue. Tried and successfully worked with bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: You can refer this [http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select]

Comment: One small thing: I think it is best practice to keep the `require_tree .` statements (those with the dots) at the bottom of all the require statements.

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes
application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"});
});
```

application.cs

```
 *= require jquery.ui.all
```

View file

```
<%= text_field_tag :birth_date,'', :class => "datepicker" %>
```

Comment: It outputs a text field which has inside: {:class=>".datepicker"}

Comment: checkout i have edited my answer. i didnt recognized that it was a text_field_tag i thought it was a text_field

Comment: getting closer..not it just outputs an empty text field..and if I click inside it, nothing happens.

Comment: did u add `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` in gem and restart rails server then try
One more thing
    <%= text_field_tag :birth_date,'', :class => 'datepicker' %>
there is no "." before 'datepicker'

Comment: I have the jquery-ui-rails. But it's version 4.0.4. Maybe this is the cause of the problem? In the Gemfile I wrote 'gem jquery-ui-rails'

Comment: removed the dot, restarted the server, from the beginning the include in the Gemfile was there.. :(

Comment: check if that text_field_tag is getting that class do inspect element in your browser and see

Comment: yes, it does <input id="birth_date" class="datepicker" type="text" value="" name="birth_date"></input>

Comment: nup, tried that as well, hoped for a miracle, and yet reality punched me into the face..